# Compare sytem time to user input time php mysql

Tags: php, mysql

I have a form and one of the requirements I need from the user is a specific time. this is done via a drop down menu. An example of a time in the drop down menu is

```
<option value="06:00:00">6:00 AM</option>
```

The above saves time as 06:00:00 in mysql database.
However I need to compare this time to the current system time but I get a null value. I tried comparing it with time() but it doesnt work. Converting the 06:00:00 to unix time using strtotime function gives me 838:59:59 as the saved time value in my database for ALL time options.

How can I compare the User input time to the system time. All help will be appreciated.

Comment: compare means `<= >= ==` what... ?

Answer (score 1):

6AM isn't a timestamp. 6AM on February 7th is a timestamp.

You can't compare them. 6AM is both before 6AM on February 7th (because there was a 6AM yesterday) and after (because there is a 6AM tomorrow).

Once you define what you want this 6AM to mean in your application, you should have some idea how to compare it to the current time (hint: add a date).

Comment: I totally understand you. However I want to send a reminder to someone at 6 AM everyday for a time period specified i.e the user gets to specify from which date till which date he/she wants the reminder. The server basically checks for reminders every hour e.g 6AM, 7AM and so on and and if it gets one, sends an sms

Answer (score 0):

use `mktime` and `time`

```
    <?php  
      $lastpost = mktime(5,15,0,10,1,2002); // mktime is as follows (hour, minute, second, month, day, year)

        $timenow = time();

        if ($timenow > $lastpost ) {
        return true;
        } else {
        return false;
        }

?>
```